# Python and Visual Studio Code - How do I run a specific file in the editor?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am writing a small application with Visual Studio Code and Python. My application has two files, `Main.py` and `MyCustomClass.py`. `Main.py` is the entry point to the application, `MyCustomClass.py` contains the logic code to solve some problems.

Currently, the debugger is set to run whatever the active file is. Is it possible to configure Visual Studio Code to run a specific file versus the active file in the editor?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `program` setting in your launch configuration settings refers to the Python script that will be executed. By default, it is set to `${file}` which refers to the file you are actively editing. Just set the value to the file you want to run.

```
{
   "name": "Python",
   "type": "python",
   "request": "launch",
   "stopOnEntry": true,
   "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
   "program": "main.py",  // Specify the full path to your file
   "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
   "env": {},
   "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
   "debugOptions": [
       "RedirectOutput"
   ]
},
```

I should mention that if you are using Windows you can use either forward slashes `/` or double back slashes `\\` in the program path. Single back slashes won't work.

Comment: I should mention that if you are using Windows then you can use either forward slashes ("/") or double back slashes ("\\").  Single back slashes won't work.

Comment: Yes, but amend that to your answer as an edit, not a question.

Answer (score 30):

You need to edit your *launch.json* file. A quick way to do it is to click [the wrench icon on the run toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FEg9.png):

[image]

---

Then add the following to the *launch.json* file:

```
    {
        "name": "Python: main.py (Integrated Terminal)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.py",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
```

Above is my configuration, and the "program" line is what does the magic.