# Vscode: always running the same python file when pressing the run button

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

By default the run button always runs the file you're currently viewing, and it's annoying because most of the time I don't want that: I'll be editing another file and then want to run my main.py file, so instead I have to go in the main file and *then* execute it. How can I change this?
I tried looking online but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Hi.
Try to check this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113247/python-with-visual-studio-code-run-specific-file

Comment: hi thanks, i tried looking at it and doing it but it still only executes the current file for some reason

Comment: Hi, do you use `F5` as the post did?

Comment: thank you, i didn't see that part and now it works. is there a way to set it as the default behaviour of the run button though?

Answer (score 6):

Create a **launch.json** file in the *Run and Debug* panel, and then replace the configuration `"program": "${file}",` with `"program": "./main.py",`.

[image]

**File structure**

```
pytest11
|-.venv
|-.vscode
| |-launch.json
|-demo.py
|-main.py
```

**launch.json**

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "./main.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Then select `Run Without Debugging`, or use the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>to run the code.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klEeh.png)

In here, may have several python terminals. Close all and compile again.